# How to dynamically whitelist api.mailgun.net IPs?

Tags: api, mailgun, whitelist, opnsense

- I have a web app running behind an OPNsense firewall
- That firewall allows all https traffic to api.mailgun.net
- The webapp calls api.mailgun.net but the resolution is different from the firewall one

It seems api.mailgun.net resolves regularly to a different set of IPs. I tried to look for know IPs but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to add a rule to your firewall that dynamically checks whether the connection is going to a domain that resolves to this IP.

However, as you already tried, adding every IP they have to the firewall is a solution. To get all possible IPs I'd do:

```
// Find the authoritative nameserver
// Your local nameserver potentially only returns the cached, first record
$ dig api.mailgun.net IN SOA
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mailgun.net.            899     IN      SOA     ns-1447.awsdns-52.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

// Query that for all the records
$ dig +short api.mailgun.net IN A @ns-1447.awsdns-52.org.
34.200.7.26
52.200.96.214
52.73.0.101
52.21.40.223
52.86.239.198
34.232.33.59
```

---

Or you just need to add a rule that allows all incoming TCP response traffic for connections you make. Assuming all outgoing traffic is allowed anyways.

To do this, add an incoming ACCEPT rule covering the [Ephemeral Port Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port):

- Source/Dest IP: any
- Source port: any
- Dest port: 32768-65535
- Protocol: TCP
- TCP flags: ack